# Executável Python não funciona o chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Fiz um código que utiliza o caminho até o arquivo chromedriver e funciona normalmente no meu computador. Criei um programa executável, mas como o caminho que está o chromedriver é diferente em outros computadores, não funciona. Alguém sabe como resolve isso?

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Users...\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo que você utilize o Chromedriver.exe na raiz da pasta de sua aplicação, assim vai evitar esse tipo de erro. Coloque o chromedriver dentro da pasta de sua aplicação em desenvolvimento (No mesmo lugar que seu main.py), logo em seguida mude seu código de:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Users...\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
```

Para:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Dessa forma o selenium vai procurar o arquivo do chromedriver dentro de sua raiz e vai evitar qualquer tipo de problema. Após ter feito isso, basta deixar sua aplicação executável, e logo em seguida pegue o arquivo do Chromedriver e coloque na pasta onde está o seu arquivo .exe (Executável).

Comment: Obrigada, funcionou!